# UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE response when using SSL termination

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx

I have a node.js server running on `http://localhost:8080` and then nginx serving it up to port 80 so it's visible to the world. The DNS though looks at a load balancer which has SSL termination.

When trying to make a request to the applications API which is on different domains but behind the same load balancer `403 {code: "UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE"}`.

Why is node trying to verify the SSL certificate if it's not running on SSL?

Comment: There is probably SSL. Check the URL you actually access  and for redirects to SSL.

Comment: All the domains have SSL (API and application) but the SSL gets terminated at the load balancer so node shouldn't be able to see it, unless my understanding of SSL is incorrect.

Comment: Where do you get the error - in your client or in the node server?

Comment: In the node server

Comment: In this case it is the node server who is trying to reach some site with SSL when the specific API gets called. Check your code what the node server is doing when you call the API.

Comment: The code is making a request using superagent to make a call to the API `e.g. https://api.application.com`. The error parameter contains the object I've given in the question.

Comment: so the error is than probably caused by this call. This is unrelated if the node server is itself on SSL because this code inside the node server makes a call to some other SSL site and can not verify the certificate of the server it tries to access.